# SQLAlchemy joins on one to many

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I need help on how to achieve this in SQLAlchemy - joining two tables.

Where

1. `Product` - has many Events
2. `Event` - belongs to Product

Events table has any of the values

- created-invoice
- approved-invoice
- item-pickup
- item-delivered
- item-cancelled

I only need the `Product`s where its related `Event` has no item-pickup, item-delivered or item-cancelled
Since the Product has many Event, a Product usually contains all event values describe above, so I just need to return all Product if its related Event table has no `item-pickup`,`item-delivered` or `item-cancelled`

I tried:

```python
param_list = ['item-pickup', 'item-delivered', 'item-cancelled']
 
stmt = (select(Product.id, Product.consignment_id, Event.name)
    .join(Product.events)
    .filter(Event.name.not_in(param_list))
    .group_by(Product.id)
    .order_by(Event.name.desc()))
```

But it still return all Product , even if one of the Product has an `item-cancelled` in Event table.

Models

```python
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = ...
    cost = ...
    events = relationship(
        'Event',
        back_populates='products',
        cascade='all,delete-orphan')
  
  
    class Event(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'events'

        name = Column(String(255))
        product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'))
        product = relatioship('Product', back_populates='events')
```

Comment: What is returned when you use the code you've tried?

Comment: @NickK9 its returning all products.My goal is to return only Products when its related table Event has no `item-pickup`, or `item-delivered` or `item-cancelled`. Product has many Event and Event belongs to one Product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally make it work

```
  event_lists = ['item-pickup', 'item-delivered', 'item-cancelled']
  stmt = select(Product.id, Event.event).join(
    Product.events).filter(~Product.events.any(Event.event.in_(event_lists))).group_by(Product.id)
print(stmt)
```